# Is the [multiple] tag needed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-block-request

The [multiple](/questions/tagged/multiple) tag seems like a bit of a mess to me. It is most often used when the title/problem contains the word "multiple" and they had a spare tag available for use. Burninate?

At 518 questions strong, it seems like a lot of effort to do this manually.

Comment: This tag doesn't meaningfully categorize the question in any way.  I believe it should be blacklisted.

Comment: Ugh, it's because of the way some people tag posts. If the title is "How do I create multiple categories in Wordpress" the tags end up being [how][create][multiple][categories][wordpress] Blacklist this tag, it means nothing on it's own.

Comment: Looks like [join][multiple][tables] is another top choice.  Sigh.  I'm also entirely unsurprised to see PHP at the top of the related tag list.