# Burninate the [mulitple](sic) tag

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

> **Possibly not a multilpicate**
>   [Is the [multiple] tag needed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120547/is-the-multiple-tag-needed)

Creative spelling has [created a monster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mulitple) (albeit with a mere 29 heads). It should be euthanized.

Comment: Hmm, so we have mulitple [multiple] tags?

Comment: There can be only one!  Well, none, as `multiple` is gone.  Let the burnination begin!

Comment: Unlike hydra, tags don't grow when you prune them. 29 is small enough to do by yourself.